# The controller.type method does not work correctly inside the onpress event - Pynput

Tags: python, python-3.x, pynput

I'm building a rudimentary autocomplete for my work, and it was doing fine, until I ran into this problem.

See example

```
import threading
from pynput import keyboard
from pynput.keyboard import Controller

controll = Controller()

def on_press(key):
    if(key == keyboard.Key.alt_l):
        controll.type("RIGHT !!!")
    if(key == keyboard.Key.delete or key == keyboard.Key.enter):
        return False

def handleKey():
    x = input('INPUT> ')
    print(x)

handle = threading.Thread(target=handleKey)
handle.start()

controll.type("RIGHT !!!")

with keyboard.Listener(
        on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

When you press alt, you will see the output with the wrong string;
It must be `[2] RIGHT !`, but it was pressed `[2]ight`
But note that this only happens with the method call inside the event.

[image]

Is this a known issue? Am I using it wrong? I'm really confused

I believe that only with `python3` and `pip3 install pynput`, this will make the example work

Tested with Windows 10

Comment: I don't understand problem and I can't reproduce it but I use Linux

Comment: BTW: `listener` runs in separated thread so you can run your handler without using thread - you have to run it between `... as listener:` and `listener.join()`

Comment: when I press left ALT then I see `RIGHT !!!`, not `[2] RIGHT !` nor `[2]ight`. Are you sure you run correct code?

Comment: @furas, I found that this issue is related to the terminal used, tested it on the new Windows 10 terminal and presented this issue. Today, with the old terminal, everything works normally.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue when trying to press a key while listening to a key. By my experience it is next to impossible. I have even tried to use other libraries' press functions such as pyautogui and keyboard inside of the pynput on_press function.

```
def on_press(key):
    if key = keyboard.Key.esc:
        return False
    else:
        if len(words) > i:
            # p = keyboard.KeyCode.from_char(words[i])
        pyautogui.press(word[i]) // also used keyboard.press(word[i])
            i += 1
    else:
        keyboard.Controller.press(keyboard.Key.space)

with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press, suppress=True) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

I feel like since the press action and the listen action are in different threads the program has to finish one before the other. At least that is what I gathered as I also have not found a solution to this. I also tried putting the press line after the listener.join() like this:

```
def on_press(key):
    if key != keyboard.Key.esc:
        return True

with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press, suppress=True) as listener:
    listener.join()
    if len(words) > i:
        # p = keyboard.KeyCode.from_char(words[i])
        pyautogui.press(words[i])
        i += 1
    else:
        keyboard.Controller.press(keyboard.Key.space)
```

However, this did not solve the issue either because the program finished after listening to one input and then pressing words[i] once.

Please let me know if you find something. However I may not be able to comment bc of low reputation.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue as well, and something like this worked for me (on Ubuntu 20.04):

```
from pynput import keyboard
import threading
from time import sleep

event_queue = []

event_to_callback = {
    # put your own key-to-function mapping here
    # keyboard.KeyCode.from_char('c') : deal_with_c
}

def process_events():

    while True:

        for c in event_queue:
            event_to_callback[c]() 

        event_queue.clear()

        sleep(0.2)

keyboard.Listener(on_press=lambda k: event_queue.append(k)).start()
threading.Thread(target=process_events, args=()).start()
```

This decouples the listener's thread from the controller's thread; any callbacks that invoke pynput.keyboard.Controller methods will now be executed on a separate thread, different from the one of the listener.